# Try to add a new web part but only shows "Made for email"

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, modern-experience, sitepages

When I try to add a new web part to the column, it shows only several options under "made for email", while before there're many other options like "news", "events", etc.

I have full access to this page, and this problem doesn't happen to the new page I created. But as soon as I add a "news" web part to my page, and news -> add -> new post, the other web parts won't show anymore when I edit the page. It's like the news settings are overwriting the page settings.

**Edit**:

Found an Easy solution: When posting news, on the top "page details" -> "made for email", toggle it off.*

But I still believe this is a bug, a news post should not affect the whole page setting.

Update: Microsoft Support Call confirmed problem and that MS is working on a fix. Service technician did an "diagno´stic run" on tenant and that somehow fixed the webparts, but only in private mode.

Hint: try to refresh webpage in EDIT mode if you only see "made for email" webparts. That did show up all webparts again. I am not shure, if taht is only possible after "diagnostic run" from MS support.

[image: Web part only shows "Made for email"]

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue after posting a news post. Now no matter what page Im trying to edit, when I try adding a web part, it only shows me the 'Made for email' ones. I don't see the toggle for 'made for email' in page details anywhere either. I don't know what to do.

Comment: I am facing the exactly same issue, if any good friend could please let me know how to make my home site page have normal web parts as before?

Comment: Can you explain this workaround in more detail? Not as familiar with Powershell and trying to figure out how to get to this selection.

Answer (score 0):

This change is related to new feature - "SharePoint News in Outlook" currently being released by Microsoft to all SharePoint tenants.

Maybe Microsoft is limiting other web parts (which might not be supported in outlook email) for the site page when you select "Made for email" template while creating new pages.

Microsoft 365 Roadmap ID: [124803](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=124803)

Message center post:

[image]

---

So, try to avoid using the "Made for email" page templates if not necessary and use Standard page templates like Blank, Visual, Basic Text, etc.

[image]

If you still think it is a bug from Microsoft, you can raise a support ticket with Microsoft directly and report this behavior: [Get M365 support - online support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide#online-support)

---

Good and simple workaround:

1. Do not create news article, rather create new page.
2. Include whatever webparts you wish.
3. Then promote the page to be news.
   This may not work in all cases, but should most of the time.

---

Comment: I have used the standard page but the webparts are gone. It actually happened on the home page (which is standard by definition

Answer (score 0):

seems like i was able to fix the site by applying a Microsoft theme, though that creates all sorts of links and template content that you then have to circle back and remove.

i also deleted the two new articles I created with the "made for email" templates. that seems to be the poison apple. don't use those.

Answer (score 0):

This happened on our intranet hub site as well. Using PnP Powershell to set the layout type of the page to 'Article' and then back to 'Home' fixed this for us.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite -Interactive

Set-PnPPage -Identity Home.aspx -LayoutType Article
Set-PnPPage -Identity Home.aspx -LayoutType Home

Disconnect-PnPOnline
```